# Program not working correctly? Cannot remove something from array without null point exception?

Tags: java

For this program I have a garage that hold a limit of ten cars. The following method will remove a car from the garage, but to remove a car you have to remove all cars in front of it. For example I want to move the car on the third array I will have to move the cars on the first two arrays temporarily.My issue is that my programs runs for a bit, but then I receive a null point exception. My issue is in the depart() method of the garage class.

Garage Class

```
public class Garage {

    private Car[] garage;
    private int size = 10;
   private int count = 0;
    private String plate;
    private String action;

    public Garage()
    {
       garage = new Car [10]; 
    }
     /**
     * Reads data off input file.
     *
     * @param fileName the name of the file
     */
      public void readData(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(fileName);
        plate = st.nextToken();
        action = st.nextToken();
        System.out.println("I just read " + plate + " " + action);
    }
      /**
     * Parks arriving car in garage if garage is not full.
     *
     * @param plate1 plate number
     */
        public void arrive(String plate1) {

        if (count < 10) {
            garage[count] = new Car(plate1);
            System.out.println(plate1 + " has been parked.");
            count++;
        } else  {
            System.out.println("We're sorry " + plate1 + ", at the moment we are full");
        }



     /**
             * Departs car by temporarily moving all cars in front of it.
             *
             * @param plate2 plate number
             */       
         public void depart(String plate2) {

                boolean found = false;
                int index = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < garage.length; i++) {
                    index=i;
                    if (garage[i].getPlate().equals(plate)) // if cars needs to be removed 
    {

                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }    

                }
                if (found) {
                    if (index == 0) {
                        Car[] temp = new Car[10];
                        System.arraycopy(garage, 1, temp, 0, garage.length-1);
                        garage = temp;
                        System.out.println("Car " + plate2 + " have been removed");

                    } else {
                        for (int a = 0; a < index; a++) {
                            garage[a].moved();    
                        }
                        Car[] temp = new Car[10];
                        System.arraycopy(garage, 0, temp, 0, (index - 1) );
                        System.arraycopy(garage, index - 1 , temp, index   ,garage.length - (index + 1));
                        System.arraycopy(temp, 0, garage, 0, garage.length );

                        System.out.println("Car " + plate2 + " have been removed");
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("We're sorry " + plate2 + ", has not parked in this garage");
                }

                }
            }
```

Tester Class

```
public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Garage javaGarage = new Garage();

        Scanner myFile = new Scanner(new File("garage.txt"));



        while (myFile.hasNext()) {
             String line1 = myFile.nextLine();

            // "echo print" data entered
            System.out.println("\n" + line1);

            // create Scanner object
            Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(line1);
            javaGarage.readData(line1);

            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line1);
            String plate = st.nextToken();
            String action = st.nextToken();
            if (action.equals("ARRIVE")) {
                System.out.println("ARRIVE "+ plate);
                javaGarage.arrive(plate);

            } else {
                 System.out.println("DEPART "+ plate);
                javaGarage.depart(plate);

            }

        }


    }

}
```

Car Class

```
public class Car {

    private String plate ;
    private int timesMoved = 0 ;


    public Car(String plate){
        this.plate = plate ;

    }

    public String getPlate(){
        return plate;
    }
    public void moved(){
        timesMoved++;
    }
    public int getTimesMoved()
    {
        return timesMoved;
    }
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Garage.depart(Garage.java:69)
    at Tester.main(Tester.java:37)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Please always include the stack trace with errors like that. And it's really nice to have the entire program, so that we can pinpoint the issue in 45 seconds instead of having to look at the code for 5 minutes.

Comment: @lared I uploaded the entire program.

Comment: Include the stack trace.

Comment: In which class and at which line are you getting a NullPointException

Comment: And half of the pasted code doesn't compile because it is missing some trailing `}`s

Comment: @rert588 what is a stack trace?

Comment: When getting null pointer exception stack trace shows where the error occured.

Comment: @Name What IDE are you using?

Comment: The stack trace is where your output is located. If an error occurs or an exception is thrown the stack trace appears as red. Please include that portion to your question.

Comment: Please stop defacing your question by removing all the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to get a car where it didn't arrive yet.

```
if (garage[i].getPlate().equals(plate)) // if cars needs to be removed
```

you know that the `garage` has a pool for 10 cars, but some places have a free parking space. Instead of traversing a pool, limit it only to the actual size.

Try

```
System.arraycopy(garage, 0, temp, 0, index);
System.arraycopy(garage, index + 1 , temp, index,garage.length - (index + 1));
garage=temp;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I'm not exactly sure what you mean by that or how I can do that. I'm sort of new to arrays.

Comment: I actually do understand what you mean. The garage length returns 10 at all times even thought sometimes there is not 10 cars. But how exactly can I limit it to the actual size

Comment: You have used arrays for cars but the parking space might be larger than the cars you have already parked. When you loop through the array use the actual count of cars in it, not the array length.

Comment: So will I do something like, i < count

Comment: You have a `count` variable, use it instead of arrays `length` property.

Comment: I tried that but I am still getting the same error. Could I not be copying the arrays correctly in the depart method?

Comment: You forgot to decrement the `count` variable after the car's departure. However it shouldn't concern the case.

Comment: I already did the decrement. But I am getting the same error. I am almost positive my error has to do with the copying of arrays, but I am not sure where.

Comment: If you are copying arrays then keep them filled from the `0` index, without gaps. For example if the `index=5` then shift elements to the left from 6 to 9.

Comment: I did that but I am just not sure where im going wrong. I am copying all elements except the car that needs to be removed but I am still getting an error.

Answer (score -1):

Use ArrayLists instead of arrays. It moves all the items after the removed one for you. Instead of garage[number here] you would do garage.get(number here).

Comment: I know arraylists will be better, but I need to use arrays.

Comment: Why? You are doing a lot of pointless memory copying with arrays that is prone to member errors / null pointers, etc.

Comment: @vikingsteve I know it would have been a lot easier if i used arraylists, but I am required to use arrays.